# Make HorizontalScrollView hover ViewPager/Fragments

Tags: android, layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tabs

Is there any way I can make my HorizontalScrollView (SlidingTabLayout) hover my ViewPager and its fragments instead of displaying them linearly?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.zerohora.app.fragments.ContentFragment">

    <com.zerohora.app.widgets.SlidingTabLayout
        android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Already tried FrameLayout and RelativeLayout, and it didn't work. Swipe stops working after this chang.
Also changed their marginTop, but the ViewPager always get on top of the ScrollView.

The idea here is to hide the HorizontalScrollView (SlidingTab) whener users scrolls a list in a ViewPager fragment.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a workaround for it:

First bring the view that you want to be on front of the others by calling brinToFront() method:

```
mSlidingTabLayout = (SlidingTabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
mSlidingTabLayout.bringToFront();
```

Then you can place the view wherever you want. If you want to place it on top but just after the action bar, you can do the following:

```
            // Get viewport's heigth
            WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
            Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
            Point size = new Point();
            display.getSize(size);
            int viewportHeight = size.y;

            // Get ActionBar's height
            TypedValue tv = new TypedValue();
            int actionBarHeight = 0;
            if (getActivity().getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.actionBarSize, tv, true)) {
                actionBarHeight = TypedValue.complexToDimensionPixelSize(tv.data, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
            }

            // Get status bar height
            int statusBarHeight = 0;
            int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
            if (resourceId > 0) {
                statusBarHeight = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
            }

            // Set tabs position
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.topMargin = -(viewportHeight) + actionBarHeight + statusBarHeight;
            mSlidingTabLayout.setLayoutParams(params);

            //Redraw display
            mSlidingTabLayout.invalidate();
            mViewPager.invalidate();
```